# React-Leaflet: Uncaught TypeError: pointToLayer is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to use the pointToLayer parameter in the GeoJSON component. I defined the the function pointToLayer outside of the component ( different file) and I get getting that error.

Map.js:

```
import {pointToLayer} from '../helpers/helper-country-point';
<GeoJSON>
      key={_.uniqueId()}
      data={this.props.activeCountry.geojson}
      pointToLayer={pointToLayer(this)}
 ></GeoJSON>
```

The file ../helpers/helper-country-point is :

```
import L from 'leaflet';
export function pointToLayer(feature, latlng) {
  return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
    color: 'white',
    fillColor: 'white',
    fillOpacity: .8,
    radius: 3,
    stroke: false
  }).bindPopup("MESSAGE") // Change marker to circle
}
```

When I define pointToLayer inside Map.js and use:

```
<GeoJSON
 key={_.uniqueId()}
 data= {this.props.countrySelected.geojson}
 pointToLayer={this.pointToLayer.bind(this)}
 ></GeoJSON>
```

It works. Any idea of why I keep getting this error ?

Answer (score 2):

In the first one, you are invoking the function and using `this` as the argument.

In the second one, you are not invoking the function. You are simply passing the function as props. You can try removing the `(this)` part in your first example, so you only pass the function without invoking it.

Then, since the error is `pointToLayer` is not a function, and it is resolved when you declare the function in `map.js`, I suspect that you might have written the wrong path to the `helper.js` file.

Comment: I removed the this, passing the function without invoking it and it worked. The path was correct. Thanks!